# Another South "table does not exist" issue: none of the previously posted solutions working

Tags: django, django-models, django-south, database-migration, django-settings

I am trying to make an app using Django and am using South to handle migrations. After I define the app's models.py, I include south in the "INSTALLED_APPS" in settings.py. Then I sync my database. When I validate the database, I get 0 errors. Then I execute the following commands on the command prompt:

```
C:\Users\abagaria\Desktop\IntegrateID\website>python manage.py schemamigration w
ebsite.integrate --initial
Creating migrations directory at 'C:\Users\abagaria\Desktop\IntegrateID\website\
website\integrate\migrations'...
Creating __init__.py in 'C:\Users\abagaria\Desktop\IntegrateID\website\website\i
ntegrate\migrations'...
 + Added model integrate.Publisher
 + Added model integrate.Author
 + Added model integrate.Book
 + Added M2M table for authors on integrate.Book
Created 0001_initial.py. You can now apply this migration with: ./manage.py migr
ate integrate

C:\Users\abagaria\Desktop\IntegrateID\website>python manage.py migrate website.i
ntegrate
Running migrations for integrate:
 - Migrating forwards to 0001_initial.
 > integrate:0001_initial
FATAL ERROR - The following SQL query failed: CREATE TABLE "integrate_publisher"
 ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, "name" varchar(30) NOT NULL, "address" varc
har(50) NOT NULL, "city" varchar(60) NOT NULL, "state_province" varchar(30) NOT
NULL, "country" varchar(50) NOT NULL, "website" varchar(200) NOT NULL)
The error was: table "integrate_publisher" already exists
 ! Error found during real run of migration! Aborting.

 ! Since you have a database that does not support running
 ! schema-altering statements in transactions, we have had
 ! to leave it in an interim state between migrations.

! You *might* be able to recover with:   = DROP TABLE "integrate_publisher"; []
   = DROP TABLE "integrate_author"; []
   = DROP TABLE "integrate_book"; []
   = DROP TABLE "integrate_book_authors"; []

 ! The South developers regret this has happened, and would
 ! like to gently persuade you to consider a slightly
 ! easier-to-deal-with DBMS (one that supports DDL transactions)
 ! NOTE: The error which caused the migration to fail is further up.
Error in migration: integrate:0001_initial
DatabaseError: table "integrate_publisher" already exists
```

I know that a lot of people have faced similar problems while using south, but usually in their case, they make the mistake of executing the "--initial" command more than once-- thereby causing south to make more than one __initial file in the migrations directory. But in my case, South thinks that the table already exists even when I make the first migration!

I have also tried:

- deleting the migrations directory
- deleting ghost migrations
- making a "fake" migration
- and then running the actual migration

Can someone please tell me how I fix this problem and can start defining my models again?

Comment: Also, these are the results for ./manage.py syncdb:
Installing custom SQL ...
Installing indexes ...
Installed 0 object(s) from 0 fixture(s)

Synced:
 > django.contrib.auth
 > django.contrib.contenttypes
 > django.contrib.sessions
 > django.contrib.sites
 > django.contrib.messages
 > django.contrib.staticfiles
 > django.contrib.admin
 > south
 > website.integrate

Not synced (use migrations):
 -
(use ./manage.py migrate to migrate these)

Comment: Did you try dropping the tables as suggested in the error message?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have tables in database, do not use --initial, instead you need convert_to_south command. Delete directory "migrations", all tables from database and run the following commands:

```
python manage.py syncdb
python manage.py convert_to_south appname
python manage.py syncdb --migrate
```

http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/convertinganapp.html